# Zombie.js does not execute synchronous ajax requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, zombie.js

I am trying to run this code using zombie.js:

```
var jqXHR = $.ajax({
  url: url,
  method: 'GET',
  dataType: 'html',
  async:false
});
var data = jqXHR.responseText;
console.log("data: " + data);
```

This code runs well when run on my browser and fetches the html from given url correctly, but when I run it through zombie.js, it doesn't make any GET request and the log always prints "data: undefined".

If I remove the "async" flag and add a success callback, the success callback runs fine, but I cannot understand why synchronous requests are not working.

Can someone tell me how to make synchronous ajax requests work on zombie?

Comment: https://github.com/assaf/zombie/issues/417 `There's no support for sync XHR and never will be.`

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to refactor my code to make this async.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As A. Wolff mentioned in the commets, Zombie doesn't support sync XHR: [github.com/assaf/zombie/issues/417](http://github.com/assaf/zombie/issues/417)

I refactored my code to make the call async based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/3676145).